# Instagram embed's stopped working in Safari - November 2022

Tags: wordpress, safari, instagram, embed

All was working fine in all browsers but all of a sudden instragram embed's (even recently added ones) stop displaying in Safari on iphones (but not chrome & firefox & not safari on a mac), and show the "view this post on instagram" link without displaying the image.

Any ideas? I'm thinking maybe something to do with the width? If not a certain width, it displays the "view this post on instagram" message?

Comment: You can try clearing the browser cache and purging the cache from your site plugin, server, and cdn.

Comment: I tried clearing the cache's but to no avail. The problem temporarily went away but came back again. Could it be something to do with the instagram embed's rendering upon the page loading? As I noticed in chrome and firefox, it initially showed the "view this post on instagram" for a second then the full embed.

Comment: Ok, so on ios safari only it is throwing a 429 bad request error back? Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Too many

```
<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

contained within my page was causing the 429 error. I removed one and it worked again.